# Shiny + Leaflet reactive function not working

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, react-leaflet

My data consists of columns like lon , lat, region, flat-type and year. I have used leaflet and shiny to create a map with cluster markers.

I included 2 selectInput boxes - one for year and one for the flat-type. Using the reactive function, it keeps giving me this error whenever I run the shiny app.

> Error: Don't know how to get location data from object of class
>   reactiveExpr,reactive

Here's my code

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Transactions for Resale Flats"),
    h3("Model A Flats: 3-Room, 4-Room, 5-Room"),
    sidebarLayout(position = 'right',
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("year","Year", choices = c("2007","2008",
                                                   "2009","2010","2011",
                                                   "2012","2013","2014",
                                                   "2015","2016","2017"), selected="2007"),

            selectInput("type","Flat-Type",choices = c("3 ROOM",'4 ROOM',"5 ROOM"),selected = "3-Room"),
            width = 2),
        mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap",height = 650,width=605)))


)


server <- function(input,output, session){

    headlinedata<-reactive({
        headlinedata%>%
            filter(year %in% input$year & flat_type %in% input$type)
    })

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data=headlinedata) %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
            label = paste(headlinedata$address,',',headlinedata$town))

          })

    observe(leafletProxy('mymap', data=headlinedata()))%>%
    clearMarkers()%>%
    addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
               label = paste(headlinedata$address,',',headlinedata$town))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also this code

```
  observe(leafletProxy('mymap', data=headlinedata()))%>%
        clearMarkers()%>%
        addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                   label = paste(headlinedata$address,',',headlinedata$town))
```

Whenever I include this, the app will run for a second and then close immediately. This code is supposed to update the map markers whenever the input changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to refer to reactive variables as the variable name followed by `()`. In `output$mymap`, you refer to `headlinedata`, which is the data frame to be filtered, when it should be `headlinedata()`, which is the reactive variable that's already been filtered. To disambiguate the two, I changed the name of the reactive variable to `df`. Then, when that reactive variable is needed in code downstream, I refer to it as `df()`.

Second, since `df()` is a reactive variable and we've set up the leaflet to depend upon it, whenever the reactive variable changes, the map will also change. This means we don't need the `observe(leafletProxy ...` code.

Here's a reproducible example you can copy and paste.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
headlinedata <- data.frame(year = rep(2007:2017, 10),
                           flat_type = sample(c("3 ROOM",'4 ROOM',"5 ROOM"),
                                         110, replace=T),
                           lat = sample(1:50,  110, replace=T),
                           lng = sample(1:50, 110, replace=T),
                           address = "address", 
                           town = "town")

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Transactions for Resale Flats"),
    h3("Model A Flats: 3-Room, 4-Room, 5-Room"),
    sidebarLayout(position = 'right',
                  sidebarPanel(
                      selectInput("year","Year", choices = c("2007","2008",
                                                             "2009","2010","2011",
                                                             "2012","2013","2014",
                                                             "2015","2016","2017"), selected="2007"),

                      selectInput("type","Flat-Type",choices = c("3 ROOM",'4 ROOM',"5 ROOM"),selected = "3-Room"),
                      width = 2),
                  mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap",height = 650,width=605)))


)


server <- function(input,output, session){

    df<-reactive({
        headlinedata%>%
            dplyr::filter(year %in% input$year & flat_type %in% input$type)
    })

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data=df()) %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                       label = paste(df()$address,',',df()$town))

    })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```